# Why is NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification received twice?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have this code in my AppDelegate

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     NSLog(@"+applicationDidBecomeActive");
     NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
     [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)  name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
     NSLog(@"-applicationDidBecomeActive");
 }

 - (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
     NSLog(@"+defaultsChanged");
     // Get the user defaults
     // NSUserDefaults *defaults = (NSUserDefaults *)[notification object];
     NSLog(@"-defaultsChanged");
 }
```

`applicationDidBecomeActive` is fired only once, when the application is launched.

If defaults are not changed, `defaultsChanged` is not fired.

But, if defaults are changed `defaultsChanged` is fired twice, one after another.

I can not understand why. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you quite certain that you only changed ONE thing in the defaults? If you change multiple defaults, then `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` will be sent multiple times. I use a similar method in some of my apps, and I have never encountered this error. This makes me inclined to think that multiple defaults must have been changed.

Comment: This doesn't sound right.  In my app, I sometimes get called once and sometimes twice in a row, and it doesn't matter whether one item gets changed or many.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding an observer every time the app becomes active.  After the second time the app is active, I think you'll have the observer registered twice and receive two notifications.  Shouldn't the registration go in one of the didFinishLaunching variants?

Comment: The easiest thing is to put it in the

Answer (score 0):

I see you have marked the question as answered, but I noticed you have two NSLog statements in the defaultsChanged: method. Maybe the method isn't called twice but you are logging the call twice.